# problems using joins with current_user from devise - cannot understand joins

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, devise

I'm still new to rails I have the following problem:

I have been following a video from reference http://railscasts.com/episodes/163-self-referential-association, because I want to create friendships between users in my web application. It seems to work.

**Problem:** I am using devise for log into my rails application, and it seems like I cannot use joins with current_user. Its using select, and I dont want to use select. I want to use joins and joing user, friendships and comments together - what should I do in order to use joins instead of select? **Remember:** I am logged in and I'm using from device current_user, which I use for getting users friends comments

I tried:

```
   class SearchController < ApplicationController
      def index
          @friendships = users_comments
      end

      def users_comments
        current_user.joins(:friendship)
      end

      def show
      end
    end
```

I got the following error:

```
undefined method `joins' for #<User:0x00000003ece840>
```

model is looking like this now **because I cannot seem to use joins with current_user object**:

```
  class User < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :friendships
    has_many :friends, through: :friendships
    has_many :inverse_friendships, class_name: 'Friendship', foreign_key: 'friend_id'
    has_many :inverse_friends, through: :inverse_friendships, source: :user

    devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
       :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
  end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

then the controller:

```
class SearchController < ApplicationController
  def index
      @friendships = users_comments
  end

  def users_comments
    current_user.friendships.first.friend.comments
  end

  def show
  end
end
```

If i use users_comments in a browser i get the following in my console:

```
User Load (1.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."id" = 6  ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1

  Friendship Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "friendships".* FROM "friendships"  WHERE "friendships"."user_id" = $1  ORDER BY "friendships"."id" ASC LIMIT 1  [["user_id", 6]]
```

It doesnt matter how you join them together I just would like an example how to use join with current_user, because my main problem is using devise current_user with joins

Comment: You can do one more has_many :through - for sample, User has_many :friends_comments, through: :friends and use it in your controller

Comment: hmm, would you like to give en answer to the question? :). I just dont want it to use select, but make a join query instead

Comment: that would be `User.joins(:friendships)`

Comment: and how am i suppose to use User.joins(:friendships) with current_user ?